# java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.net.SocketPermission" "127.0.0.1:1099" "connect,resolve")

Tags: java, server, rmi

I am getting this error when I try to run the server. I updated my policy in security.policy. This is my policy file.

```
grant codeBase "file:C:/.../workspace/RMIServerSide/bin/" {
 permission java.security.Allpermission;
};
```

My main method:

```
public static void main (String[] argv)throws RemoteException, MalformedURLException {
               try {

                   System.setSecurityManager(new RMISecurityManager());

                   Addition Hello = new Addition();     
                   Registry registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099);

                   Naming.rebind("localhost", Hello);

                   System.out.println("Addition Server is ready.");
                   }catch (Exception e) {
                       System.out.println("Addition Server failed: " + e);
                    }
               }
```

Answer (score 0):

Either:

1. `"file:C:/.../workspace/RMIServerSide/bin/"` isn't the correct codebase, or
2. Your .policy file wasn't found, which you can see by starting the server JVM with `-Djava.security.debug=access,failure`.

However, unless you're using the RMI codebase feature with the clients providing the .class files, you don't need the security manager in the server JVM at all. Just remove it.